# How to check a specific value is displayed inside a table in Selenium Web driver

Tags: java, selenium

[image: Active]

I am trying to validate a specific text inside a Table in a web page. the text is "ACTIVE". There are other places on the same page which displays the same text. But I wanted to check "ACTIVE" within that table.

I tried using driver.getPageSource().contains("ACTIVE"); - However, this validates the entire page.

The Xpath of the element is :

html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqW6q.jpg)/td/table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqW6q.jpg)/tbody/tr/td/table[4]/tbody/tr/td[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqW6q.jpg)/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]

And here the html below

```
<html>
<head>
<body leftmargin="2" topmargin="2" onload="initializeData()" marginwidth="2" marginheight="2" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<table width="756">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="9"/>
<td width="764">
<form frm_id="frm" name="frm">
<table width="754" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

<table height="629" width="763">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td height="625" width="770">
<table width="728">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table height="10" width="739" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<table height="10" width="736" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<table height="4" width="740" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<table height="86" width="100%" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td height="80" width="33%" valign="top">
<table height="267" width="103%" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td height="20" width="47%" align="left">Current Status</td>
<td height="20" width="155%">
<b>:</b>
 ACTIVE 
</td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this XPATH expression:

```
//tr[ *[ text() = 'Current Status' ] ]/td[ b ]
```

it finds TR element which contains a direct child with `Current Status` text, and then it selects it's direct child TD ( a child of TR) which contains B tag.


or directy select second TD tag:

```
//tr[ *[ text() = 'Current Status' ] ]/td[ 2 ]
```

---

You can also use this

```
//tr[ *[ text() = 'Current Status' ] ]/td[ text() = 'Active' ]
```

in order to check if `Acive` text is present or visible on the screen in a field (row) named `Current Status`.